# Manage multiple logins and register accounts in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

i am trying to develop a app which has three account types **student login**, **tutor login** ,**institute login** i have developed three apps named student, tutor and institute but when i am registering a user in student app then by that username i can also login into the tutor app also. So how to manage all types of accounts..

**forms.py file**

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #Student_Name= forms.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email Address")
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label="Confirm Email")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Confirm Password")
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','password','password2','email','email2']

    def clean_password2(self):
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        print(password, password2)
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        else:
            return password

    def clean_email2(self):
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('email2')
        print(email, email2)
        if email != email2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Email addresses don't match")
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if  email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email has already been registered")
        else:
            return email


class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

        #user_qs = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        #if user_qs.count() == 1:
        #   user = user_qs.first()
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user does not exist")
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user is no longer active")
            return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
def register_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())

    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        return render(request, 'app/register_sucessfull.html',{})

    context = {
        "form": form,

    }
    return render(request, "app/register.html", context)

def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    w="Welcome"
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return render(request,'app/index1.html',{'username':username,'w':w})
        #return redirect('student_view')


    return render(request, "app/login.html", {"form":form, "title":title})
```

**same code in all the remaining apps**

Comment: the authentication should be 1 app by itself.

Comment: @Mox I already tried that method but doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MandeepThakur Thanks man for the upvotes.I know that It's you :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Django auth Group for three different groups i.e. student, tutor and, institute and assign different permissions to all of them for different logins. You can create a new model named Permissions and add diffrent permisions to all gropus,lile this :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='yourapp', model='Your_model')
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_login',
                                       name='Can login as tutor ',
                                       content_type=content_type)
user = User.objects.get(username='some_name')
group = Group.objects.get(name='tutor')
group.permissions.add(permission)
user.groups.add(group)
```

For further reading, [Read from here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Group)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to differentiate users by their roles. But what you do is not correct way to do that. Django has permissions and groups to solve this problem. Actively use Django permissions in order to show or hide some elements on the page. The same for actions. Trust me, you do not want to create custom authentication places for every role in your system.

Create `Students`, `Tutor`, `Institute` django groups and than change what you show when they loggen in by their permissions. This is the only Django way to solve your problem